# Python selenium select option from angular js drop down

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please open this website- https://mobikwik.com/
There is a form for Mobile with 2nd item as Select Operator.
I want to select - "Idea" from this drop down using selenium webdriver.
Please help.

Also, after selecting idea, i get a new drop down for select circle. Need to select Mumbai for it.

My attempt:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li > span.ng-binding").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[3]/i").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("font > label > i").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[@id='mainunit']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[4]/p/dl/dd/ul/li[9]/span").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//font/label[2]/i").click()
```

Comment: Try this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='ng-scope'][9]").click()`.

Comment: To complete the comment of @JasonEstibeiro, first try:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding']").click()`
To make the options visible, and the click the option:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='ng-scope'][9]").click()`

Comment: Or this seems like a better option. Give it a try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding' and text()='Idea'][1]").click()`. Let me know if any of them work.

Comment: Both options throw the same error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with` 

Looks like first you have to unfold the options and afterwards select it.

Comment: @Javitronxo - Realized it now. I had actually manually clicked on it (the `ng-binding` span). Anyways, upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this code with same webpage and worked:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Select Operator')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Idea')]/..").click()
```

It is essential that you first make visible the options pannel, otherwise it will throw the following exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

**Updated:**

To select the Mumbai option:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Select Circle')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Mumbai')]/..").click()
```

Comment: Thanks....it wroked...i have updated my question....n tried a lot to implement the same by refering the code you provided..."after selecting idea, i get a new drop down for select circle. Need to select Mumbai for it"....can you help plz

Answer (score 1):

first click the select box then choose the option, to choose the vodafone you need to click 3rd child :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".select").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".options > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(3)").click()
```

other options are as the following:

```
.options > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(2) => Artiel
.options > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(3) => Vodafone
.options > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(4) => BSNL
```

after you select the first select box there are 2 select box, you can select it samely but by `find_elements_by_css_selector()` with pulural

```
# select first one
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".select").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".options > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(3)").click()
# select second selectbox
# you may need to sleep until second selectbox is available
sleep(1)
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".select")[1].click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".options.open > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(5)").click() # 5 option is Mumbai
```

Comment: Thanks....it worked...i have updated my question....n tried a lot to implement the same by refering the code you provided..."after selecting idea, i get a new drop down for select circle. Need to select Mumbai for it"....can you help plz

Answer (score -1):

`floorselectionWait = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="select_22"]')))
        floorselection=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="select_22"]')
        floorselection.click()
        flooroptionsWait = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//DIV[@class='md-text ng-binding'][text()='Level 7']")))
        optionSelect=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//DIV[@class='md-text ng-binding'][text()='Level 7']")
        optionSelect.click()`
angularjs md-select md-option selecting in selenium  python